# Is it safe to consume roasted rice as a substitute for coffee beans?

Tags: flavored-coffee, coffee-culture

In the Philippines some people roasted their rice to make a substitute for coffee, this rice is uncooked rice. But I doubt if it is safe?

Comment: Why would uncooked rice be unsafe? Rice is generally stored in non-airtight containers at room temperature for indeterminate storage times.  Do they use rice before it's dried after harvest, or something like that?

Answer (score 7):

While I never heard of rice as [coffee-substitute](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_substitute), people have used roasted malted barley, spelt, chicory or dandelion roots or even acorns (and other foods) to make a dark, aromatic brew that was used either separately or mixed with coffee, especially in times of scant resources.

I suppose the rice would not be burnt<sup>1</sup> (because that would taste horrible), but roasted instead. Healthwise it is perfectly safe, like the other options mentioned above. Just note that rice has no caffeine, so you wouldn't get the "kick" you get from real coffee.

---

<sup>1  original post said "burnt", has now been changed to "roasted"</sup>

Comment: Ah yes, what I mean is roasted not burned. How about cancer? I heard that you can get that in burned / roasted foods?

Comment: @CaryBondoc I'm not a scientist or healthcare professional, but considering the amounts consumed (you don't *eat* the grains), I think the risk is minimal. Again, that's *my personal opinion, not a recommendation or similar*.

Answer (score 3):

Since i was a child my mother always cooked roasted rice or we call that SARA SARA,I feel better everytime we drink it as replacement of coffee,but i suggest not to burn too much coz it taste bitter
As on our experienced i noticed there's no side effect,it's just my opinion
Just try it sometimes but don't take it everyday

Comment: So why not have it every day? Many have several coffees a day.

Answer (score 2):

i was diagnosed for an acid reflux and taking coffee is a No- no...then i took rice coffee/roasted rice as substitute and find it good! no caffeine and it makes me burp after a couple of minutes taking it..,it's called "tinutong" in bicol..'coz when i was a young:) my mom sometimes made it for me..then now i take it again...it's been 5 months now that i didn't take any coffee anymore...thanks to "tinutong na bigas" as my rice coffee! i recommend this for you, guys! no more acid reflux and of course be also aware and prevent from taking foods not suited for those with hyperacidity...i'm taking research on it..^-^....- Vanz Alpheus :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the Philippines and yes we do roasted rice to make coffee here.  It was the practice here in some provinces. Several days ago i tried roasting approx 50 grams of rice to make some coffee. I was told that it is a healthful substitute for the popular coffee of our generation. Just like what was said in the other comment, "there's no punch in it like the coffee beans." But there's something unique about its taste that you will want some more after downing a cup.  Healthful? i am not sure.  still doing some research that's why i came across this page.